# ionic2 build fails when adding cordova-plugin-photo-library plugin

Tags: swift, cordova, ionic2

I'm working on an ionic2 app, as soon as I run:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-photo-library
```

and then attempt to build the app:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

I get the multiple errors, ending in

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.